# Error en entorno virtual (VSCode) con Django y Python

Tags: django, vscode, virtualenv

Siguiendo un tutorial de internet (https://dev.to/iamjonathanpumares/configura-tu-entorno-de-desarrollo-de-manera-profesional-con-python-y-django-335g), he creado un entorno virtual, donde he instalado **Django**, seleccionando antes el **intérprete de Python ('venv':venv)**.

He creado una carpeta **settings**, con una serie de archivos en los que en uno de ellos he pegado **settings.py**, para una configuración en local y producción.

Al ejecutar **python manage.py runserver**, me da error:

**NameError: name 'BASE_DIR' is not defined**

En el tutorial se indicaba que el código de **settings.py** había que pegarlo en un archivo (**base.py**) de la carpeta de creación nueva **settings**. Esta nueva carpeta tiene otros archivos **.py** además de **base.py: init, local y production**. Es en **local.py** donde me aparece por primera vez el error. Este es el código de **local.py**:

```
    DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
            "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
        }
    }


    STATIC_URL = "static/"

    from .base import *
```

Este el código de **base.py** (donde se ha pegado **settings.py**):

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
]

DJANGO_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = []

LOCAL_APPS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "proyecto_django.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "proyecto_django.wsgi.application"
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]
LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"

from decouple import config

SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
def verify(path):
    path = Path(path)
    if path.exists():
        return path.resolve()
    else:
        raise ValueError("Path %s does not exist" % path)
```

En este **base.py** he probado tanto con la solución que me ha ofrecido Ulises Antonio como con la que venía del tutorial y con las dos a la vez pero, el error sigue (captura):

[image: Error en la consola de VSCode]

Y este el código de **manage.py**:

```
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proyecto_django.settings.local')
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proyecto_django.settings.production')


    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Edorta, sería de mucha utilidad, que nos mostraras tu código para así poder darte una ayuda fundamentada..

Comment: Hola Marce Puente. ¿Me podrías decir si te refieres a los archivos de configuración o solo al de mi proyecto? Gracias

Comment: El mensaje de error, dice que "BASE_DIR" no está definido, en algún lugar haces mención a una variable que no está creada. creo que en el archivo **manage.py**, es lo que tendriamos que ver.

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es subir la linea *from .base import * arriba de todo

Comment: Solucionado. Gracias a todos!!

Answer (score 0):

El error `"NameError: name 'BASE_DIR' is not defined"` significa que no estás usando una variable definida llamada `"BASE_DIR"`. En Django, `BASE_DIR` se utiliza para hacer referencia a la ruta base de la aplicación, y es una variable común en archivos `settings.py`.

Para solucionar este problema, agrega la siguiente línea al comienzo de tu archivo settings.py:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Esto importa el módulo `os` y establece `BASE_DIR` como la ruta completa al directorio padre del archivo `settings.py` actual.

Después de agregar esta línea, guarda el archivo y vuelve a ejecutar `python manage.py runserver`. Debería funcionar correctamente sin el error `"NameError: name 'BASE_DIR' is not defined"`. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

La solución es sencilla, estas llamando a la variable `"BASE_DIR"` antes de declararla, haz el
`from .base import *` al principio del archivo **local.py**, así no repetirás código.

```
from .base import *

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
    }
}


STATIC_URL = "static/"
```